# In loot 2.0 do drop geared depend on our gear quality?

Tags: diablo-iii

I have a well made wizard with 330k damage. Most drop gears would lower the DPS of course. However, not by much.

I also have a demon hunter lvl 60 with a mere 25k DPS. It's amazing how most drop gears do not improve her attack.

What's wrong?

I suppose if drop gear does not depend on current gear, we would expect my demon hunter to get higher rate of "improving" gears. Her gears sucks.

My wizard will have higher rate of worse gears because her gears are top end.

That's not what I see.

Levels are the same. 60 and now with shared paragon level. Difficulty is almost the same. Torment 1 vs Torment 3

Comment: Remember that because your wizard kills at a much faster rate you tend it get a lot more gear as well.  That might skew the rate a bit.

Comment: If your Wizard was made pre-2.0, and the demon hunter hit lvl 60 post-2.0, then bear in mind that gear now will be slightly worse due to the changes with mobs being capped at lvl 60 until the expansion (whereas before they could actually be higher than 60 in higher difficulties).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First thing first:  Gear drop level (understand quality) is tied to your character's level (1-70); you can loot the same quality legendaries/gear when you are level 70 in Normal difficulty or Torment 6.

Then the answer is no, but the phenomenon you are witnessing can be easily explained:

A well geared character has pieces of equipment that synergize well together (crit damage, crit chance, Intelligence in your case, attack speed, etc.) for an overall good DPS. Since your Wizard is well geared any piece of equipment you add will synergize with the others. Let's take a quick example:

- If your gear brings you a lots of crit damage already, a new piece of equipment that brings some crit chance will fit well with your overall gear.

This explains why when you loot something for your wizard, since your gear is good you might not have a DPS upgrade.  However, the loot still syngerizes with the rest of the gear and so the DPS drop is not that much.

On the other hand your Demon Hunter doesn't appear well geared meaning that the chance of a new loot synergizing and thus increasing your DPS is very low. And a loot that lowers your DPS will appear worse on your DH since the rest of your DH's gear can't make up for its worse stats.